# Error on Connecting with database

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I am getting an error when i am connecting my site to database

```
    Error in file: "/site-path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access         violation: 1142 ALTER command denied to user 'username' for table 'core_layout_link'
```

Comment: The error is quite precise: your db user doesn't have ALTER privilege on tables on that database. Give it more privileges. DB users love privileges

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to ALTER a table in database. Add privileges to this database on the particular table, re-connect and try to ALTER. By the way check whether user has got privileges too.

Comment: As is noted, the magento database user needs all privileges except grant on the database. Set through root login with phpmyadmin or from the mysql command line.